# Should you reduce images' size before giving them to Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader

When the users selects an image to be used as a background in my app, I reduce the image size to fit the screen's dimension, save it in the cache and then give the URI of the file I created to Universal Image Loader to show the image on the screen. I was wondering if this practice was useless, if Universal Image Loader already does this in the background. Do you think I should crop images or let Universal Image Loader do its job?

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are 4 ways to handle OOM questions:
1, intervene the handling efficiency of Dalvik by hand:
    eg:VMRuntime.getRuntime().setTargetHeapUtilization(0.7);
2, set the size of Android Heap by hand:
    eg:VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize(8*1024*1024);
3, use gc to release resource:
    eg:if(bitmap != null && !bitmap.recycled()){bitmap.recycle();System.gc();}
4, zoom bitmap out: eg:halve size of bitmap
hope that it is helpful to you